# How to stop infinite loop in JShell / Kulla?

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop, jshell

JShell is a Java REPL that is scheduled to be released alongside Java 9; however, there is an open beta for it.

If I create an infinite loop in JShell (Project Kulla) by typing:

```
-> while(true) {}
```

JShell will loop forever. Short of completely quitting JShell, is there a way to stop an individual line of code while it's running in JShell (after you have already begun evaluation of the code)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is a way. Just hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>:

```
-> while(true) {}
Killed.

->
```

It'll kill the loop and will **not** exit the shell.

Note that it'll take ~1-2 seconds for the kill process to finish, if you hit it twice it'll kill the statement and then will exit the shell.

<sup>I'm using [JDK 9 EA build 107 on 03-01-2016 (#4560)](https://jdk9.java.net/jigsaw/)</sup>

Comment: "Short of completely killing JShell"

Comment: @DanielM. This will *not* kill the JShell, will only terminate the infinite loop.

Comment: I must have hit it twice by accident then

Comment: @DanielM. that's why I wrote the final note.